# Where to find a permanent link to IE WebDriver Tool for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I'd like to use Microsoft's webdriver tool to run automated end to end tests against a web application.  As part of our build process we automatically download and install the required webdriver components for the various browser so that no manual setup is needed.  However I am unable to find a permanent link that we could use to automatically fetch the IE WEbdriver tool found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44069). Is anyone aware of one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no permanent link for WebDriver components. Evidently from the URL itself, the links varies from one browser to another. Here's a different one for Microsoft Edge and it may change soon enough once a new version arrives:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?**id=48212**

Similarly with Selenium, each version has its own URL

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

So the manual process of keeping track of the links can't be avoided. You might want to consider changing your approach in your build process